# Is there a better way to find specific value in a python dictionary like in list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been practicing on iterating through dictionary and list in Python.

The source file is a csv document containing Country and Capital. It seems I had to go through 2 for loops for country_dict in order to produce the same print result for country_list and capital_list.

Is there a better way to do this in Python dictionary?

The code:

```
import csv
path = #Path_to_CSV_File
country_list=[]
capital_list=[]
country_dict={'Country':[],'Capital':[]}
with open(path, mode='r') as data:
    for line in csv.DictReader(data):
        locals().update(line)
        country_dict['Country'].append(Country)
        country_dict['Capital'].append(Capital)
        country_list.append(Country)
        capital_list.append(Capital)

i=14 #set pointer value to the 15th row in the csv document

#---------------------- Iterating through Dictionary using for loops---------------------------
if i >= (len(country_dict['Country'])-1):
    print("out of bound")

for count1, element in enumerate(country_dict['Country']):
    if count1==i:
        print('Country = ' + element)

for count2, element in enumerate(country_dict['Capital']):
    if count2==i:
        print('Capital = ' + element)
#--------------------------------Direct print for list----------------------------------------

print('Country = ' + country_list[i] + '\nCapital = ' + capital_list[i])
```

The output:

```
Country = Djibouti
Capital = Djibouti (city)
Country = Djibouti
Capital = Djibouti (city)
```

The CSV file content:

```
Country,Capital
Algeria,Algiers
Angola,Luanda
Benin,Porto-Novo
Botswana,Gaborone
Burkina Faso,Ouagadougou
Burundi,Gitega
Cabo Verde,Praia
Cameroon,Yaounde
Central African Republic,Bangui
Chad,N'Djamena
Comoros,Moroni
"Congo, Democratic Republic of the",Kinshasa
"Congo, Republic of the",Brazzaville
Cote d'Ivoire,Yamoussoukro
Djibouti,Djibouti (city)
Egypt,Cairo
Equatorial Guinea,"Malabo (de jure), Oyala (seat of government)"
Eritrea,Asmara
Eswatini (formerly Swaziland),"Mbabane (administrative), Lobamba (legislative, royal)"
Ethiopia,Addis Ababa
Gabon,Libreville
Gambia,Banjul
Ghana,Accra
Guinea,Conakry
Guinea-Bissau,Bissau
Kenya,Nairobi
Lesotho,Maseru
Liberia,Monrovia
Libya,Tripoli
Madagascar,Antananarivo
Malawi,Lilongwe
Mali,Bamako
Mauritania,Nouakchott
Mauritius,Port Louis
Morocco,Rabat
Mozambique,Maputo
Namibia,Windhoek
Niger,Niamey
Nigeria,Abuja
Rwanda,Kigali
Sao Tome and Principe,São Tomé
Senegal,Dakar
Seychelles,Victoria
Sierra Leone,Freetown
Somalia,Mogadishu
South Africa,"Pretoria (administrative), Cape Town (legislative), Bloemfontein (judicial)"
South Sudan,Juba
Sudan,Khartoum
Tanzania,Dodoma
Togo,Lomé
Tunisia,Tunis
Uganda,Kampala
Zambia,Lusaka
Zimbabwe,Harare
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your point; Please check out the code.

```py
import csv
path = #Path_to_CSV_File
country_dict={}
with open(path, mode='r') as data:
    lines = csv.DictReader(data)
    for idx,line in enumerate(lines):
        locals().update(line)
        country_dict[idx] = {"Country":Country,"Capital":}

i=14 #set pointer value to the 15th row in the csv document

#---------------------- Iterating through Dictionary using for loops---------------------------
country_info = country_dict.get(i)
#--------------------------------Direct print for list----------------------------------------

print('Country = ' + country_info['Country'] + '\nCapital = ' + country_info['Capital'])
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Now I know there's a less roundabout way of doing this.